# Get Last X months in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I get the current month like this

```
today = date.today().replace(day=1)
print("Today's date:", today)
today.strftime("%B")

>> Today's date: 2019-09-01
>> 'September'
```

I want to now return a list of months like this (say last 6, including current)

```
>> [September, August, July, June, May, April]
```

How can I get this list?

Comment: you want to get list of remaining months from today's date month??

Comment: yes, I want to get remaining months name, in decreasing order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
result = [now.strftime("%B")]
for _ in range(0, 6):
    now = now.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    result.append(now.strftime("%B"))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['September', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'April', 'March']
```

Comment: range(0, 5) gives 6 months

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the latest "6 or less" months:

```
import calendar
import datetime

MONTHS_NUM = 6
today_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
first_month = max(today_month - MONTHS_NUM, 0)
last_months = calendar.month_name[1:][first_month:today_month][::-1]
print(last_months)
```

**Output:**

```
['September', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'April']
```

But if the month is May or less, the result list will be shorter:

```
['May', 'April', 'March', 'February', 'January']
```

So you can use this code to get circular list that always contains 6 months:

```
import calendar
import datetime

MONTHS_NUM = 6
double_months_list = calendar.month_name[1:] * 2
today_month = datetime.datetime.now().month + 12
first_month = today_month - MONTHS_NUM
last_months = double_months_list[first_month:today_month][::-1]
print(last_months)
```

**Output:**

```
['May', 'April', 'March', 'February', 'January', 'December']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datetime import date

today = date.today().replace(day=1)
min_month = max(today.month - 5, 0)
month_range = range(today.month, min_month, -1)
print [today.replace(month=i).strftime("%B") for i in month_range]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()

month = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
            "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

print( month[today.month-1:] )
```

Comment: maybe i misunderstood the sorting criteria first :)

Comment: Hey, this is not the right answer, getting this 'December', 'November', 'October'

Comment: I thought you are wanting it backward :(  edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

using python list comprehension

For getting complete month name like Ex:- ['September', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'April']

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

completeMonthName =[ j.strftime("%B")for j in [(date.today() + relativedelta(day=1,months=-i)) for i in range(0,6)]]
print(completeMonthName)
```

for getting partial month name like Ex:- ['Dec', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Jul', 'Jun']

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

completeMonthName =[ j.strftime("%b")for j in [(date.today() + relativedelta(day=1,months=-i)) for i in range(0,6)]]
print(completeMonthName)
```

Change loop value for getting less or more months name